# Windows 10 driver load order

Tags: windows

I have a windows kernel driver, that has to check for a specific string in SMBIOS table and if the string is available, the driver will load. Else, the driver is not loaded.

It is implemented and works fine on installation. But when the system is restart / shutdown and start, the driver load fails because of the SMBIOS string is not available.

We believe that the mssmbios.sys that is responsible for loading the SMBIOS table is not installed while the driver is trying to do SMBIOS string check.

Can anyone help us in specifying in some way that mssmbios.sys should be available for our driver to start?

---

Edit

We tried:

1. Change LoadOrderGroup
2. Change Dependencies

In our `inf` file

```
ServiceType = 1
StartType = 3
```

In mssmbios.inf

```
ServiceType = 1
StartType = 1
Group =
```

Comment: Google has all the obvious answers when you query it for "windows specify driver load order".  Show some evidence that you already tried the recommended solutions so we don't have to repeat them all over again.

Comment: @HansPassant check edit